# How can I submit the question that's on hold for review again?

Tags: support, review, on-hold-questions

One of my questions were put on hold and I was told to edit it so that it fits the website, so I did edit it. Now how do I submit it for review?

Comment: Some details about how edits get post into the reopen review queue can be found [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/16820/should-i-avoid-minor-edit-of-a-question-which-was-put-on-hold/16821#16821).

Answer (score 4):

This happens automatically, but only for the first edit. Namely, if the question was edited and the reviewers felt that it should be left closed then even after future edits it won't get sent automatically to the review queue.

To overcome this problem, you can also post a request on [Requests for Reopen & Undeletion Votes, etc. (volume 01/2015 - ) [current version]](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/19042/requests-for-reopen-undeletion-votes-etc-volume-01-2015-current-versio) explaining why you think that your question should be reopened.

Comment: I will add that edit has to fulfill some additional conditions (most important seems to be to make the edit within the 5 days). Details can be found in [the answer I linked above](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/16820/should-i-avoid-minor-edit-of-a-question-which-was-put-on-hold/16821#16821).